# Problem with defining variables in python

Tags: python, variables, lxml

I'm trying to write some xml by this piece of code

```
docs = XmlReportGenerator()
docs.AddMatchRow('FC Barcelona','Madryt','5:0')
docs.Save()
```

and I wrote my own method:

```
from lxml import etree

class XmlReportGenerator:
    """"""
    root = etree.Element('results')
    doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        """""" 

    def AddMatchRow(self,teamA,teamB, score):
        pageElement = etree.SubElement(root,'Flight',teamA, teamB, score)

        """"""

    def Save(self,path = None):
        outFile = open('Matches.xml', 'w')
        doc.write(outFile)
```

NameError: global name 'root' is not defined
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
done

NameError: global name 'doc' is not defined
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
done

Am I missing something? I'm a newbie in python (I have more experience in c#).

Comment: If you're writing code without comments anyways, there's no point spamming it with `""""""`. Doesn't add anything and actually isn't even counted as a pydoc in case of `AddMatchRow` (it's after some statements). Use `# comment` is you want some visual separation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is explicit.  Instance variables must be prepended with `self.`.  Class variables must be prepended with then name of the class.

Here's a fixed version.  The original `SubElement` call was incorrect as well:

```
from lxml import etree

# derive from 'object' if Python 2.X (it is default in Python 3.X)
class XmlReportGenerator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # clearer to init instance variables here.
        self.root = etree.Element('results')
        self.doc = etree.ElementTree(self.root)

    def AddMatchRow(self,teamA,teamB, score):
        # Need self.root here
        pageElement = etree.SubElement(self.root,'Flight')
        # Added data elements (or did you want attributes?)
        etree.SubElement(pageElement,'teamA').text = teamA
        etree.SubElement(pageElement,'teamB').text = teamB
        etree.SubElement(pageElement,'score').text = score

    def Save(self,path = None):
        outFile = open('Matches.xml', 'w')
        # Need self.doc here
        self.doc.write(outFile)

# This code will run if the script is executed directly,
# but will be skipped if the script is imported by another script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs = XmlReportGenerator()
    docs.AddMatchRow('FC Barcelona','Madryt','5:0')
    docs.Save()
```

Answer (score 2):

`self` is there for a reason. Use `self.root`, not `root`

Comment: @khachik or that, depending on the context. Generally, `self.root`